# Flexera InstallShield failing to install window-service app built with Windows 10 - Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, windows-10, installshield-le

I am using Flexera Software InstallShield limited edition with visual studio 2013 to deploy my window service, this worked well with windows 8.1; I was able to install and reinstall this service on several servers.  Today, I upgraded my development environment to windows 10, rebuild this windows service successfully, however when installing the service, InstallShield threw error 1001. I rebuild other windows service apps that previously had no problem installing, InstallShield threw the same error 1001 for all other window service apps. Please note that I uninstalled a service before reinstall it. Is this a known issues? Has Flexera Software acknowledged this issue? Has Flexera software released a hot fix for this issue? thank you.

Comment: Try asking at Super User.

Comment: I have exactly this problem too, except that the installer was previously built with Windows 7.  My dev envt is a clean install of Windows 10 Enterprise.

Answer (score -1):

I am looking for the same issue. What did I? Roolback to windows 8.1, cleaned my registry and it works (on win 8.1)

Comment: This is very unhelpful.  Rolling back is not necessarily an option.